# Angular2 / Jasmine: Testing Service with another Service as a dependency

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

Setup: an APP_INITIALIZER service `ConfigurationService`, which loads config data, is being used across app components and services. When unit testing components, it reads the config file and evaluates correctly. When unit testing services, which use configuration, it fails.

It is set up as follows:

**app.module.ts**

```
export function ConfigurationFactory( config: ConfigurationService ): any {
  // this line actually triggers the loading of the config file  
  return () => config.load(); 
}

@NgModule({
  bootrstrap: {},
  ...,
  providers : [
    ConfigurationService,
    {
      deps: [ ConfigurationService ],
      multi: true,
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: ConfigurationFactory,   
    }
  ]
})
```

**ConfigurationService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

  // error holder
  public error: boolean = false;
  // data holder
  public data: any = {};
  // config file url
  private configUrl: string = './assets/config/config.json';

  constructor( private http: Http ) {
  }
  /**
   * reads config file
   */
  public load(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get( this.configUrl )
      .map( ( response: any ) => response.json() )
      .toPromise()
      .then( ( data: any ) => this.data = data )
      .catch( ( err: any ) => Promise.resolve() );
  }

}
```

Here is the **TestableService.service.ts** which uses the config service, too

```
@Injectable()
export class TestableService extends SomeAbstractHttpService {
  constructor( http: Http,
               private config: ConfigurationService ) {
    super( http );
  }

  public setRequest( sessionId: string, isIdent: boolean ): void {
    if ( isIdent ) {
      this.resourceUrl = `${ this.config.data.contextRootRest}/documents/ident/${sessionId}`;
    } else {
      this.resourceUrl = `${ this.config.data.contextRootRest}/documents/noident/${sessionId}`;
    }
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    this.headers.append( 'Accept', 'application/json, application/pdf' );
    this.requestOptions = new RequestOptions( {
      headers: this.headers,
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
    } );
  }
}
```

Now to spec file, **TestableService.service.spec.ts**

```
export function ConfigurationFactory( config: ConfigurationService ): any {
  return () => config.load();
}

describe( 'TestableService', () => {

  // not ideal to hardcode it here, I would prefer using the same config file, which is used across the app!
  let mockConfig: any = {contextRootRest: 'rest/'};
  let theService: TestableService; 

  beforeEach( async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        TestableService,
        MockDataService,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        ConfigurationService,
        {
          // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
          deps: [ ConfigurationService ],
          multi: true,
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: ConfigurationFactory,
        },
      ]
    } );
  } ) );

  // I suspect, that using APP_INITIALIZER at this stage is goofy, 
  // as I do not in fact instantiate the app, only the service. 
  // What would be the correct way to do it here?

  beforeEach( inject( [ TestableService, XHRBackend ], ( service: TestableService, backend: MockBackend ) => {
    theService = service;
    mockBackend = backend;
  } ) );  

  it( 'should set request correctly', ( ) => {
    theService.setRequest( '1234567890', true );
    expect( theService.resourceUrl )
        .toEqual( `${ mockConfig.contextRootRest }/documents/ident/1234567890` );
  });
});
```

And it fails with `Expected 'undefined/documents/ident/1234567890' to equal 'rest/documents/ident/1234567890'` - which means, that the Config service has not been loaded at the TestableService at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is actually bad. We figured out the way a couple of hours later and here is a much cleaner and better solution.

So, as the config file is in our assets directory, we can actually import it directly into the spec file. We have also used a mocked provider for ConfigurationService and that's it. Here is the **spec.ts** file

```
import { ConfigurationService } from '../../common/config/configuration.service';
import * as config from '../../../assets/config/config.json';

const mockConfig: any = config;

export class ConfigurationFactory {
  // no methods as in the original ConfigurationService, just the object var
  public data: any = mockConfig;
}

describe( 'TestableService', () => {

  let theService: TestableService;

  beforeEach( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
      providers: [
        TestableService, ...
        { provide: ConfigurationService, useClass: ConfigurationFactory },
      ]
    } );
  } );

  beforeEach( inject( [ TestableService ],
      ( service: TestableService ) => {
        theService = service;
  } ) );

  it( 'should set request correctly', ( ) => {
    theService.setRequest( '1234567890', true );
    expect( theService.resourceUrl )
        .toEqual( `${ mockConfig.contextRootRest }/documents/ident/1234567890` );
  });
}
```

Another example of things being solved in ways too complicated where a much simpler solution is on the surface... :/